# Canon Rebel Not Working

Tags: canon

Hey my canon rebel stopped working. It was working fine earlier when I took pictures of my dogs and I didn't realize how low the battery was and it died. I took it inside and charged it and about 30 minutes later came inside to look at the cute pictures I got. I plugged it into my computer and a message popped up that said change the battery pack. I haven't changed it yet because I don't have a new battery but wanted to know if there was a way around having to go and buy a new battery. Now my camera won't even say that. It is just off and won't turn back on. Please help

Answer (score 6):

"change the battery pack" just means your battery is too low and needs to be charged. 30 mins was probably not long enough. Charge it until it is fully charged and your camera should be working again.

If you still get the message after a full charge, the battery contacts on the battery or camera may need cleaning.

If cleaning doesn't work, you may have to buy a new battery.

If you don't plan on using the camera much, and want to avoid buying a new battery for it, you can download the photos directly from the memory card to a computer using a memory card reader.